# High voltage testing of multi core cables

Tags: voltage, current, high-voltage, cables, testing

I was going through Indian standards for high voltage testing of multi core PVC insulated cables (Up to 1.1kV). Can someone please guide me with the following two points.

A) Connection to be done in 12 core and 20 core cables?

B) What is the purpose for the second point (for more than 4 cores) mentioned?

Below is a snippet from the Indian standard:

[image]

Link to the full standard [IS 10810-45 (1984): Methods of Test for Cables, Part 45: High Voltage Test [ETD 9: Power Cables]](https://law.resource.org/pub/in/bis/S05/is.10810.45.1984.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience in this sort of testing but I read it as follows:

[image]

*Figure 1. Testing a layer with even and odd number of cores. Image original.*

- To test core to core insulation on a layer the polarity is reversed on each adjacent conductor as shown in (a). All the blues can be connected to one terminal and all the reds to the other. This allows testing of the whole layer in one test.
- In (b) which has an odd number of cores we can see that there are two blues side by side so they would not be stressed by the group test. As a result the first and last cores would need to be tested separately.

Comment: Niicely explained. Thanks for the answer. 